# Convert from dfm to dtm

Tags: r, quanteda

I try to use the coherence metric calculation as reported [here][1].

I work with quanteda so I have a dfm

However in the link the use a dtm:
#create DTM

```
dtm <- CreateDtm(tokens$text, 
                 doc_names = tokens$ID, 
                 ngram_window = c(1, 2))
#explore the basic frequency
tf <- TermDocFreq(dtm = dtm)
original_tf <- tf %>% select(term, term_freq,doc_freq)
rownames(original_tf) <- 1:nrow(original_tf)
# Eliminate words appearing less than 2 times or in more than half of the
# documents
vocabulary <- tf$term[ tf$term_freq > 1 & tf$doc_freq < nrow(dtm) / 2 ]
dtm = dtm
```

How is it possible to use the option of dfm instead of dtm in this calculation

More specifically how is it possible to create the vocabulary using the dfm and the dtm option?
[1]: https://towardsdatascience.com/beginners-guide-to-lda-topic-modelling-with-r-e57a5a8e7a25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `convert()`.  e.g.

```
convert(yourdfm, to = "topicmodels")
```

or

```
convert(yourdfm, to = "tm")
```

See `?convert`.